# Angular material dialog, subscribe problem on closing dialog

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am using Angular 6.1 and Angular material 7.0.1

This is my BoardComponent

```
createBoard(): void {
 const dialogConfig = new MatDialogConfig();
 dialogConfig.panelClass = 'custom-dialog-container';
 this.dialog.open(CreateDialogComponent, dialogConfig);
 this.dialog.afterAllClosed.subscribe(
  data => console.log(data);
 );
}
```

And this is my CreateDialogComponent, I will put only function for saving data

```
saveBoard(): void {
  const board: any = this.boardForm.value;
  this.dataService.createBoard(board).subscribe(response => {
   if (response.status === 'created') {
    this.dialog.closeAll();
   }
  });
}
```

Everything works great, I open CreateDialogComponent and send data to my service. But when I close my dialog my response for *this.dialog.afterAllClosed* is undefined. Is there some another method to pass any params when dialog is clossing?

Thank for help!

Comment: you can use a `Subject` setted by the `save` from the dialog to your main component that will do the work

Comment: @JacopoSciampi I tried now with Subject and everythink works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

AfterClosed is a function. To call it use:

```
this.dialog.afterClosed().subscribe
```